# SEVERE : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring and i'm not able to figure out the problem.please help me on this.I m getting classnotfound exeption even there is package defined in my src location.

and i have added a listener as you can see it is commented in web.xml contextListener class.it is also defined in the src code but it is giving classNotFound exception.please suggest and help me on this

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance
  of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.org.promo.beans]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to    convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.org.promo.beans]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 20 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class   
 [com.org.promo.beans]
at
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:272)
at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:63)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:430)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:403)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:128)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
... 26 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.org.promo.beans
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:269)
... 34 more
```

and here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com
/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">



<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<!--    <listener>
          <listener-class>
           com.org.promo.properties.ContextListener
          </listener-class>
</listener>  -->   

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`

And this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Base package for checking the annoted classes -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.org." />

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  > 
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

 <!-- Configure JDBC Connection-->
  <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SAMPLE_DB" />
        <property name="username" value="admin_user" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
  </bean>


  <!-- Configure Hibernate 4 Session Facotry -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
              <value>com.org.promo.beans</value> <!-- Entity classes-->
        </list>
        </property>

  </bean>
```

Comment: I highly doubt that `com.apalya.promo.beans` is a class. You probably wanted to set the `packagesToScan` property instead of the `annotatedClasses` property of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

Comment: yes Deinum,i made that mistake and ran the build again by rectifying it,but now i 'm getting same type of error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apalya.promo.entity.User.where User class actually exists in my application

Comment: Not according to the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Since **com.org.promo.beans** is a package not class, hence it complains `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class`.

You supposed to use `packagesToScan` property instead of `annotatedClasses` OR configure fully qualified entity class name(s) if you still want to continue with `annotatedClasses`.

Comment: i have made that change, i gave fully qualified entity class name but still shows the same error, i think thats not the actual issue Lovababu ,there might be some mistake in configuration xml file,please help on this

Comment: Please update the question with new configuration change, and error.